# average of particular filed in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

i have a crystal report i want to find average of cntEcode value
so i try to add new formula field AverageEcode then i try to give code like that.
Average{DriverPerformance.CntEcode}
.but while saving showing error:
There is an Error with this formula.
Do you want to save any way.
how i can calculate average of particular field using formula filed. I attached picture what i try to do..how i can find out average of this values,If any one know.please help me to find out.
[image]

My

Answer (score 1):

just give like this: sum({DriverPerformance.CntEcode}) / count({DriverPerformance.CntEcode})..then We Will get exact average value

Answer (score 0):

Use a running total field to create the average.  This will also give you the ability to average, sum, max, min, etc. by group.  It will also give you the ability to add filters (if needed)